# VBA Macro to search for value then increment

Tags: vba, excel

I just learned about macros this week and am looking for some help (if my question is even possible)..What I would like to do is run a macro that searches column C for the #1..then in each of the cells below it increase the number until it reaches a full cell (the next section)..then find the next #1 and so on and so forth until the end. If something like this is possible any guidance and expertise is appreciated! I've added a mock-up below. Also keep in mind I've used small numbers for the example.

Pre-macro

[image]

Post-Macro

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer via the ol' macro recorder:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Range("C1:C10").Select
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
  Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
End Sub
```

**Edit: Update to populate within a region made contiguous based on fully populated column B as per comments.**

```
Sub Macro2()
  Range("B1").Select
  Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
  Selection.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 1).Select
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
  Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
End Sub
```

**Or, if not contiguous, but wishing to populate to the last row populated in column B**

```
Sub Macro3()
  Range("B1", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)).Select
  Selection.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 1).Select
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
  Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Macro recorder is your friend. To do this manually, select the desired range. F5|Special... to select blank cells. Type your formula and hit Ctrl-Enter to populate all the selected (blank) cells.

Comment: See that is what is troubling me. The range is unknown because you never know how small or large the sheet could be.

Comment: Couple of options: (1) If there is other data making the region contiguous you can expand to the `CurrentRegion`. (2) If the regions are non-contiguous (entire blank rows separating) then go to the last possible cell on the sheet, e.g. `Range("C1048576").Select` for Excel 2010. and then `Selection.End(xlUp).Select` to get to the last populated cell.

Comment: @Golf_pro90 There lies a problem with your goal as far as I can see. A macro can be built that would work just fine for the first section, but after the first section the macro would continue increasing the cell value until the end of the sheet (>million rows). Is there any other data on the sheet that the macro could reference to tell it when to stop?

Comment: +1 @ARich OP will need to include some logic to tell the macro when to *stop*, otherwise, it won't stop.  In the example, the last (S2) set of data stops at "3".  How can the macro know to stop at 3 instead of 4, or 409, or 1,048,576?

Comment: @ARich the Section number and Case number will be filled all the way down in there respective columns..sorry I should have filled those for the mock-up..

Comment: In that case the `CurrentRegion` approach should work to help you identify the end. Or use the `End(xlUp)` approach on a fully populated column to find the last row.

Comment: @DavidZemens ..so when we hit the final test case section could the macro reference the last cell in either col A or B that has a value? then it would know where to stop